Proving the cartesian closedness of the slice category $\mathcal{T}/I$ of a topos $\mathcal{T}$ for the Fundamental Theorem of Topos Theory.
I'm currently working on topos theory and I'm trying to prove the "Fundamental Theorem of Topos Theory", which states that for a topos $\mathcal{T}$ and an object $I \in Ob(\mathcal{T})$ the slice category $\mathcal{T}/I$ is also a topos.
I primarily followed the proof in Handbook of Categorical Algebra 3 by F. Borceux (Theorem 5.8.1) and I understand almost all of it, except the part about the cartesian closedness, where he proves the bijection $$\mathrm{Hom}(\gamma,\beta^\alpha) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\gamma \times \alpha, \beta)$$
by succesively proving bijection between sets inbetween. I understand all the steps and I accept the bijective correspondence, but what I don't understand is that for the functors $(-)^\alpha$ and $-\times\alpha$ to be adjunct, the Hom-sets need to be naturally isomorphic and he makes no mention of naturality.
The other sources I've found that have this theorem, like Johnstone's Topos Theory, also make no mention of naturality, except for these lecture notes that mention that the subsequent sets are in natural 1-1 correspondence, but this claim is then completely glossed over.
I assume that naturality is just super obvious in this case and I'm just not versed enough in category theory to see it, but all my tries to explicitly prove it have gone nowhere, so my question is if someone either knows another source that goes more in depth, or could give me a tip how to see the naturality of this bijection.
Edit: I've realized that I asked this question a little too generally (forgive me, this is the first time I've ever asked something on an internet forum), so let me give a little more detail:
The bijection is proven by showing bijections between the following sets:
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}/I}(\gamma:C \rightarrow I,\beta^\alpha:P\rightarrow I) & \cong \{a:C \rightarrow P\ |\ \beta^\alpha \circ a = \gamma\}\\
& \cong \{b:C \rightarrow \widetilde{B}^A\ |\ \psi \circ \gamma = \widetilde{\beta}^A \circ b\}\\
& \cong \{c:C \times A \rightarrow \widetilde{B}\ |\ \varphi \circ (\gamma, 1_A) = \widetilde{\beta} \circ c\}\\
& \cong \{d:C \times_I A \rightarrow B\ |\ \alpha \circ \delta = \beta \circ d\}\\
& \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}/I}(\gamma \times \alpha: C\times_I A \rightarrow I,\ \beta:B \rightarrow I)
\end{align}$$
Where most of those new symbols are obtained by some pullback or via cartesian closedness (I can't really go into a lot of detail here without just copying large parts of the book, but if you're interested, you can find the definitions in the lecture notes linked above).
My problem is that these sets aren't images of functors in any way that's obvious to me, so my attempts to construct natural transformations fail because I don't even know between what functors I'm trying to find a transformation.
I assume that this question probably cannot be answered without someone explicitely going through the proof, but maybe there's an obvious flaw in my thought process here and there actually is a much easier way to see it.

My opinion is that it's more natural to prove that power objects exist in the slice category, and then use the general construction of power objects based on limits and power objects.  The direct construction I can think of for exponentials in a slice category has definite echoes of that general construction.

Anyway, in general, if you can check that each step is a natural isomorphism, then you can use that isomorphisms of functors are closed under composition.  And typically, each step that uses an existing adjunction will automatically give a natural isomorphism.  I don't have that reference to hand to check whether that's the case there.

Oh, OK, it looks like its construction of the exponential in the slice category is based on partial function classifiers, which I guess makes sense because a morphism $A \times_I B \to C$ is a partial morphism $A \times B \dashrightarrow C$, and then you also want to enforce that it respects the maps to $I$.  I'd have to think some more about that construction before I could update my answer.  (I still like the construction of power objects in the slice category better, though.)

Anyway, it looks like each step should be a contravariant functor in $\gamma$, of signature $(\mathcal{T}/I)^{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$; and if you can apply the methods or at least check manually that each step is natural, then the isomorphism of functors shows directly that $\beta^\alpha$ is the desired exponential.

It also looks like each step is a subfunctor of a simpler functor, e.g. the right hand side of the top line is a subfunctor of $\operatorname{Hom}({-}, P)$.  So at each step, if you can find a natural transformation in one direction or the other between the larger "containing" functors, then the restriction being a natural transformation will follow automatically.

@DanielSchepler this construction shows more generally that being locally cartesian closed with a subobject classifier for a class containing regular subobjects that is closed under pullbacks is implied by (and hence equivalent to) having products and cartesian homs into classifiers of partial morphisms with domain subobject in that class. Cartesian closure of topoi follows from power objects classifying relations corresponding to subobjects in that class being enough to construct cartesian homs into classifiers of partial morphisms which correspond as relations to subobjects in that class.

Let me present a simpler example of a chain of isomorphisms, and indicate how you would fill in the details that it produces a natural isomorphism.
The statement to prove will be: for objects $a,b,c$ in a Cartesian closed category $\mathcal{C}$, $(c^b)^a \simeq c^{a\times b}$.  A typical proof might read: we have
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}({-}, (c^b)^a) & \simeq \operatorname{Hom}({-} \times a, c^b) \\
& \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(({-} \times a) \times b, c) \\
& \simeq \operatorname{Hom}({-} \times (a\times b), c) \\
& \simeq \operatorname{Hom}({-}, c^{a\times b}).
\end{align*}
Therefore, by Yoneda's lemma, we conclude that $(c^b)^a \simeq c^{a\times b}$.
Now, to answer the question of how we know that the isomorphism is natural, we can start by observing that isomorphisms of functors are closed under composition; therefore, it will suffice to show that each step is a natural isomorphism.  Now, the first and last steps are direct applications of the role of the exponential $b^a$ as representing the functor $\operatorname{Hom}({-}\times a, b) : \mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$.  However, what about the second step, $\operatorname{Hom}({-}\times a, c^b) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(({-}\times a)\times b, c)$?  Well, the definition of the exponential $c^b$ gives an isomorphism of functors $\varepsilon_{b, c} : \operatorname{Hom}({-}, c^b) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}({-}\times b, c)$.  Now, we also have a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ which sends $u \mapsto u\times a$ and acts on morphisms as $\alpha \mapsto \alpha \times 1_a$; this then induces a functor $\mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathcal{C}^{op}$ as well.  Therefore, we can form a composition of the isomorphism of functors and the functor to get $\varepsilon_{b,c} \circ ({-} \times a)^{op} : \operatorname{Hom}({-} \times a, c^b) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(({-}\times a)\times b, c)$.
Similarly, for the third step, let us suppose we have already constructed a natural isomorphism $(a\times b)\times c \simeq a \times (b \times c)$, i.e. an isomorphism of functors $\alpha : ({-}_1 \times {-}_2) \times {-}_3 \simeq {-}_1 \times ({-}_2 \times {-}_3)$ where both sides are functors $\mathcal{C}^3 \to \mathcal{C}$.  Then we can compose on the right with the functor $({-}, a, b) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}^3$ to get an isomorphism $({-}\times a)\times b \simeq {-}\times (a\times b)$.  Then, we can take the opposite and compose on the left with the functor $\operatorname{Hom}({-}, c) : \mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$.  Overall, we have constructed an isomorphism of functors $\operatorname{Hom}({-},c) \circ (\alpha\circ ({-},a,b))^{op} : \operatorname{Hom}(({-}\times a)\times b, c) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}({-}, c^{a\times b})$.
As you can see, the overall procedure is very mechanical in nature and closely follows the syntactic structure of the argument.  This is why those details would often be omitted.

Now, with the additional details added to the question since the above part of the answer, let us see how to apply this method in that specific case.  It will be useful to note that each intermediate step is expressed as a subset of a Hom-set which is functorial in $\gamma$ or $c$.  Thus, we will start by constructing natural transformations between the containing sets, reversing the order from the chain given in the question:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}/I}(\gamma \times \alpha, \beta) & \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(C \times_I A, B) \\
& \hookrightarrow \operatorname{PartialHom}_{\mathcal{T}}(C\times A, B) \\
& \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(C\times A, \tilde B) \\
& \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(C, \tilde B^A) \\
& \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}/I}(\gamma, \pi_2 : \tilde B^A \times I \to I).
\end{align*}
Each step is a contravariant functor $(\mathcal{T}/I)^{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$ in $\gamma$ -- the second through fourth lines factoring through the forgetful functor $\mathcal{T}/I \to \mathcal{T}$ which in particular maps $\gamma \mapsto C$.
Here, the methods from the previous section of the answer will apply in most steps.  The one trickier one where you would have to do some manual checking is from the first to second line, where you map a morphism $C \times_I A \to B$ to the corresponding partial morphism $C \times A \dashrightarrow B$.  Here, you need to verify that if you have a morphism from $\gamma' = (C' \to I)$ to $\gamma = (C\to I)$, then you have a pullback square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C' \times_I A @>>> C \times_I A @>>> B \\
@VVV @VVV \\
C' \times A @>>> C \times A.
\end{CD}
Once you have checked those details, you also need to check that the image is precisely those morphisms $\gamma \to (\pi_2 : \tilde B^A \times I \to I)$ which factor through the subobject $P$ of $\tilde B^A \times I$.  If you can show that, then from this you can easily construct the desired isomorphism of functors $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}/I}({-}\times\alpha, \beta) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}/I}({-}, \beta^\alpha)$.  This is where tracing the subsets as in the quoted chain of isomorphisms will come in.  Note that it is important here that each step not just show that there exists a bijection at each step, but that the bijection is induced by the natural transformation at that step.

If you have any further questions on taking this method and applying it to the specific proof you're looking at, you would probably need to edit the question to add more details on how the reference is constructing an exponential in the slice category, and specific steps of the proof where you are having trouble filling in the details.

MathJax doesn't use equation numbering so you can just skip the star.

Thank you for your answer! Your example perfectly illustrates what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately I asked my original question in a very general way that doesn't really capture the specific problem I'm having. I have edited it to include what I'm actually struggling with.

@Maik I've expanded the answer to address your expansion/clarification of the question.
